# Dilemma with buttons within UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, uiscrollview

I've got a UIScrollView (scrollView) and a UIImageView (scrollImage). I'm trying to add buttons to a scroll view and have them resize and reposition correctly when I zoom in and out. I had the following code at first to add a button:

`[scrollView addSubview:button];`

This gave me problems with zooming in and out. The position of the buttons wouldn't stay relative to the image. So i changed it to this:

`[scrollImage addSubview:button];`

Which made everything zoom in and out nicely, however the buttons have stopped reacting to touches (I assume because they are beneath the UIScrollView).

Is there a way to have both features working correctly?

Thanks
Zac

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default a UIImageView has userInteractionEnabled set to NO. Set it to YES and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

try by setting like this,

scrollImage.userInteractionEnabled=YES